# External resources loading problems on cordova-android@12

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, backend

i'm currently working on andorid app which include loading external json file via javascript and some iframes. Obviously all is working fine on PC but not once the app is launched on an android phone.
I thought it was cordova-plugin-whitelist, but i cannot install it as it says : Unmet project requirements for latest version of cordova-plugin-whitelist:
cordova-android (12.0.0 in project, >=4.0.0 <10.0.0 required)
Fetching highest version of cordova-plugin-whitelist that this project supports: 1.3.4 (latest is 1.3.5)
.

Even when i install the latest version of the plugin, i got the error :

```
symbol:   class Whitelist
  location: class WhitelistPlugin
C:\Users\Showroom654\Documents\olga\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\whitelist\WhitelistPlugin.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        this(new Whitelist(), new Whitelist(), null);
                 ^
  symbol:   class Whitelist
  location: class WhitelistPlugin
C:\Users\Showroom654\Documents\olga\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\whitelist\WhitelistPlugin.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        this(new Whitelist(), new Whitelist(), null);
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Whitelist
  location: class WhitelistPlugin
C:\Users\Showroom654\Documents\olga\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\whitelist\WhitelistPlugin.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        this(new Whitelist(), new Whitelist(), null);
                 ^
  symbol:   class Whitelist
  location: class WhitelistPlugin
C:\Users\Showroom654\Documents\olga\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\org\apache\cordova\whitelist\WhitelistPlugin.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        this(new Whitelist(), new Whitelist(), null);
```

Thanks a lot for help

I tried to install the plugin but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: whitelist is deprecated, what version of cordova and which platforms and versions are you using ?